# Lotus Notes: change automatically location

Tags: lotus-notes

is there an option in lotus notes 6.5 that change automatically location when the user switch .id file ?
because sometimes the user switch id but do not change location so lotus notes show alarms of the location user... Which is not the current .id user...
thank's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You should instead create multiple location documents and associate each location document with the required id file.

Location documents are stored in your local names.nsf in the advanced section. Look for the setting "User ID to switch to" on the advanced tab:

[image]

To switch location (and thereby user id) you click on the current location name in the lower right corner and select a new location to switch to it.

Comment: i have already create multiple location document (one for each user) but my problem is that the location do not change when i switch id form File->Secuty-> switch id menu

Comment: That's because you need to switch location (and thereby user id). Click on the current location name in the lower right corner and select a new location to switch to it.

Comment: In addition: you "just" have to train your users to switch IDs by changing the location - which in the long run is much easier to do, anyways.

Comment: I updated my answer with info on how to switch location